# select the first element after sorting column and convert it to list in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

what is the most efficient way to sort one column in data frame, convert it to list, and assign the first element to variable in scala. I tried the following

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, first, regexp_replace}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

println(CONFIG.getString("spark.appName"))

  val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName(CONFIG.getString("spark.appName"))
    .setMaster(CONFIG.getString("spark.master"))

  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()

val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", ",").load("file.csv")
val dfb=df.sort(desc("_c0"))
val list=df.select(df("_c0")).distinct
```

but I'm still no able to save the first element as variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `select`, `orderBy`, `map` & `head`

Assuming column `_c0` is of type `string`, If it is different type you have to modify your column data type in `_.getAs[<your column datatype>]`

Check below code.

```
scala> import spark.implicits._
import spark.implicits._

scala> val first = df
.select($"_c0")
.orderBy($"_c0".desc)
.map(_.getAs[String](0))
.head
```

**Or**

```
scala> import spark.implicits._
import spark.implicits._

scala> val first = df
.select($"_c0")
.orderBy($"_c0".desc)
.head
.getAs[String](0)
```